# How to calculate left and right eigenvector corresponding to the zero eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working on $8\times8$ matrix resulting from the Jacobian of $8$ differential equation of a disease model evaluated at disease free equilibrium. I needed to get the left and right eigenvectors corresponding to zero eigenvalues. this will enable me apply center manifold in getting the stability of the endemic equilibrium.

Comment: Please avoid using all capitals, many people regard that as rude.

Comment: @MartinsOnurah: Welcome to MSE! Can you share/post the matrix so we can see what you have? We need to look at the algebraic and geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue and the structure of the matrix in order to provide actual guidance on the approach. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to calculate these things explicitly, left and right eigenvectors for the zero eigenvalue just correspond to calculating the null space of the matrix and its transpose. You can do this by hand (if you are seeking to punish yourself) by simply manually row-reducing the matrix to reduced row-echelon form.